# Simulation of electric water heater system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, simulations

I'm want to write a simulation for an electric water heaters in python. As of my current understanding of thermodynamics, I have started from the energy balance equation for open systems:

$$
dT = dH - dEnv - dOut + dIn
$$

- $dT$ = Change of energy stored in system
- $dH$ = Energy provided by electrical heater
- $dEnv$ = Losses of energy to environment
- $dOut$ = Losses due to flowing out water
- $dIn$ = Income of energy because of flowing in Water

But at this point, I cannot figure out how to calculate the temperature of the water flowing out of the system. With my current knowledge the best equation I can provide is:

$$
\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{1}{m_H + C_w} * (P(t) - L * A_H (T_f(t) - T_u) - mf(t) * C_w (T_f(t) - T_0)) + mf(t) * C_w (T_i(t) - T_0))
$$

- $m_H$:    Mass of water in Heater
- $C_w$:    Heat capacity of water
- $P(t)$:   Power provided by heating element
- $L$:      Heat transfer coefficient (Heater box to environment)
- $A_H$:    Surface area of heater
- $T_f(t)$: Temperature of water in system
- $T_u$:    Temperature of environment (constant)
- $mf(t)$:  Mass flow of water
- $T_0$:    Average temperature of water flowing into water
- $T_i$:    Current temperature of water flowing into water

As with that equation I know how the temperature in the system changes. With the initial temperature in each step, I can calculate the current temperature of the system.

$$
T(x) = T(x-1) + \frac{dT}{dt}
$$

But this don't feel quite to me. Mostly because the energy loss due to water flowing out of the system seems so be quite small.

I found some other models describing the current temperature of the outlet temperature as in

- https://recipp.ipp.pt/bitstream/10400.22/17113/1/COM_GECAD_ZitaVale_2018.pdf
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307899794_Modeling_of_Electric_Water_Heater_and_Air_Conditioner_for_Residential_Demand_Response_Strategy/link/57d0e40a08ae601b39a06539/download

My problem is, I don't understand how they get from the energy equation to the equations described in the documents (or if they even started from there). Can someone explain how they got their modell?

I am currently on the right track? Thank you in advance.

Comment: $T(x) = T(x-1) + \frac{dT}{dt}$ is not dimensionally consistent.

Comment: What's the geometry of your system?